# Cannot cast from source type to destination type iterating transform

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine

I'm fiddling around with a day/night cycle script in C# that I'm making.
I have no idea if it is any good, I'm just trying things out in C#, since I'm new to it.
I think I've got a pretty decent code here, the Debug doesn't say anything until I test out the game. When I test it, it'll say:

> InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination
>   type. cycleFlow.DayNightCycle () (at Assets/Scripts/cycleFlow.cs:28)
>   cycleFlow.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/cycleFlow.cs:14)

This is what I have got:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class cycleFlow : MonoBehaviour {

  private Color night;
  private Color day;

  void Start () {

    night [0] = 30;
    night [1] = 30;
    night [2] = 30;

    day [0] = 255;
    day [1] = 255;
    day [2] = 255;

  }

  void Update () {
    DayNightCycle ();
  }

  void DayNightCycle()
  {

    foreach (SpriteRenderer child in transform)
      if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
        child.color = Color.Lerp(child.color, night, Time.deltaTime);

    foreach (SpriteRenderer child in transform)
      if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        child.color = Color.Lerp(child.color, day, Time.deltaTime);

  }
}
```

What's going on?
(First time posting here btw, sorry if I do anything wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modification simply to get past your error:

```
foreach (SpriteRenderer child in transform.GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>())
```

Going further I'd try to keep in mind framerate. You may want to cache these renderers if you can from your `Start` function. Additionally, I'd move the `if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))` to be outside your loop instead of inside.

EDIT: Coming back to this I also notice you're only acting on key down, rather than at all times while the key is pressed. (See difference between `GetKeyDown`, `GetKey`, and `GetKeyUp`). You might try something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class cycleFlow : MonoBehaviour
{

  private Color night;
  private Color day;
  private IEnumerable<SpriteRenderer> childSpriteRenderers;

  void Start ()
  {
    night = new Color(30, 30, 30);
    day = Color.white;

    childSpriteRenderers = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer> ();
  }

  void Update ()
  {
    DayNightCycle ();
  }

  void DayNightCycle ()
  {
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Q))
    {
      foreach (SpriteRenderer child in childSpriteRenderers)
      {
        child.color = Color.Lerp (child.color, night, Time.deltaTime);
      }
    }

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E))
    {   
      foreach (SpriteRenderer child in childSpriteRenderers)
      {
        child.color = Color.Lerp (child.color, day, Time.deltaTime);
      }
    }
  }
}
```